# Kill all processes locking a file

Tags: python, windows, process

When I am running a Python script, I sometime get the error that:

> "the process cannot access the file, because it is being used by
>   another process"

Now I am wondering: Is there a way in python to:

1. Detect which process is using that file ?
2. Close this process ? (using for example `os.system('taskkill /f /im PROCESS.exe)` )

Comment: there's a handy tool for that. It's called "unlocker".

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Could you please share the link to the project page ? I cannot find it upon a first glance on Google.

Comment: french link but it's fine: https://www.commentcamarche.net/download/telecharger-34055141-unlocker

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Ah, I see. Actually, I was looking for a pythonic way of doing it, because I need this to be done automatically.

Comment: maybe the tool has a batch mode. Anyway this can be done, provided that the locked file is local, and you're running with elevated privileges

Comment: related/duplicate (with unsatisfactory answers): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544275/non-intrusively-unlock-file-on-windows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try iterating over processes and kill it if you match the file needed with psutil:

```
import psutil


for p in psutil.process_iter():
try:
    if "filename" in str(p.open_files()):
        print(p.name())
        print("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^")
        p.kill()
except:
    continue
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does the filename have to be with the complete path or just the relative path from the folder where the python script is stored ?

Comment: Depends on the filename, if it is unique you can use only the filename, otherwise you can add path too(if the name is commonly used you might kill other processes too).

Comment: This is an example output of open file by viber, and it uses full file path:psutil.Process(pid=12756, name='Viber.exe', started='2019-07-04 10:39:15')
[popenfile(path='C:\\Users\\"user"\\AppData\\Roaming\\ViberPC\\359899180789\\viber.db-wal'...

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The problem is, this does not assert that the process has the file locked. It only assess if the process has the file open. For example, it could be open by an editor but not locked.